# Potatos, black colour on leaves normal?

Tags: leaves, pests

These are pink fir apple taters in tubs.
Some of the new leaves have got dark grey patches near the stem - only near the stem like in the photo, and are a bit curled. Hoping it's not blackleg.
The grey is mostly on one plant, on recent leaves.
Would appreciate some info, thanks.
[image]

Comment: Looks fungal. I'd spray for Black Spot immediately.

Comment: The funny thing is it's all at the base of the stem on recent growth. I haven't seen a picture that looks like that. Maybe leaf roll virus? Zebra chip, purple top?

Comment: @JimmyWiddle - have you tried Googling "potato blight"?

Comment: What would be a good fungicide?